# textpath in svg not working in IE?

Tags: html, css, svg

I see IE display different  with firefox, chrome, safari...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="700" width="1300">
<defs>
    <path id="defsPath0" transform="translate(0, 0)" d="M-25,12 L75,12 M-25,32 L75,32 M-25,52 L75,52 M-25,72 L75,72" />
    <path id="defsPath1" transform="translate(0, 20)" d="M-25,12 L75,12 M-25,32 L75,32 M-25,52 L75,52 M-25,72 L75,72" />
    <path id="defsPath2" transform="translate(0, 40)" d="M-25,12 L75,12 M-25,32 L75,32 M-25,52 L75,52 M-25,72 L75,72" />
    <path id="defsPath3" transform="translate(0, 60)" d="M-25,12 L75,12 M-25,32 L75,32 M-25,52 L75,52 M-25,72 L75,72" />
</defs>
<g>
    <text x="0" y="0" font-family="MS UI Gothic" font-size="15" style="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,20)">
        <textPath id="textPath_0_0" xlink:href="#defsPath0">1</textPath>
        <textPath id="textPath_0_1" xlink:href="#defsPath1">2</textPath>
        <textPath id="textPath_0_2" xlink:href="#defsPath2">3</textPath>
        <textPath id="textPath_0_3" xlink:href="#defsPath3">4</textPath>
    </text>
</g>
```

with Firefox, chrome:
**1 

2 

3 

4**

But IE:
**1

234**

Please help me ! thank you so much !

Comment: Works for me in IE11. Which version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: how do you get SVG in IE? SVG standalone / HTML inline SVG / HTML external SVG

Comment: @altocumulus, I use IE11, only IE is not working !

Comment: @ Pavel Gatnar I use javascript make to svg !

Comment: @TanND And if you use `ctrl + u`, what do you have exactly in your `SVG` code ? (it's working on JSFiddle with IE9 emulated, btw.)

Comment: This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbsrwd7s/) based on your code which works fine in IE11, FF, Chrome. Please check if this causes the same problem within your browser setup.

Answer (score 0):

> I use javascript make to svg !

Then you should have shown us your Javascript also.

However I suspect I know what the problem is.  I am guessing you are using `createElement()` to create your SVG elements.  You need to use `createElementNS()`:

```
document.createElementNS(""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath");
```

Comment: Thank @Paul LeBeau so much,
I use 
document.createElementNS(""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath");
I fixed it
        <text x="0" y="0" font-family="MS UI Gothic" font-size="15" style="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,20)">
            <textPath id="textPath_0_0" xlink:href="#defsPath0">1</textPath>
        </text>